# Is AppTools.Init the only method that depends on physical configuration files?

Tags: configuration, configuration-files, enterprise-web-library

If not, what other parts of EWL require configuration file be at a particular location?

For the config files that AppTools.Init does require, is it possible to specify that information in a different way? (By passing the config XML directly, for example).

I'm trying to make it possible to deploy programs that use EWL to environments where I might not have full control over the file system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that `AppTools.Init` is the only part of EWL that *directly* depends on physical configuration files. But many other parts of EWL use the configuration files *indirectly* by using `AppTools` functionality that relies on the configuration files being loaded.

It is not currently possible to specify configuration information in any other way, but it would not be difficult to add support for alternative methods since this would only require modifying `AppTools.Init`.